# GitLab - Impossible to push after server maintenance

Tags: windows, git, ssl, ssl-certificate, gitlab

So, here's the thing. I'm using GitLab with some friends for a university project, and a few days ago the university shut down the platform for a maintenance. Now it's back, but I've had a lot of problems (and I'm the only one of my friends having those, so...).

For everything I try, there is this message :

> fatal: unable to access
>   '*****.git': SSL
>   certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

So I found out that by disabling SSL certification with

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

I was able to at least pull from the server. But whenever I try to push something, I have this message :

> remote: hooks/pre-receive:10: undefined method `require_relative' for
>   main:Object (NoMethodError) To
>   https://gitlab.info-ufr.univ-montp2.fr/20130118/RIR_2017.git  !
>   [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error:
>   failed to push some refs to
>   'https://gitlab.info-ufr.univ-montp2.fr/20130118/RIR_2017.git'

I guess the main problem comes from the SSL verification so I've tried a few things like exporting the certificate from the GitLab page in my browser and add it to git certificates file (ca-bundle.crt) but that didn't work.

I'm using Git Bash (an emulation for Windows), and I'm using Windows 7, it that can help.

Also, I'm new to this so sorry if I haven't given all the informations needed.

Thanks !

Comment: You should ask the university admin if they broke something. `http.sslVerify` should not be deactivated.

Comment: Thanks for you answer (and sorry to respond so late). =)
It's complicated for a student to address something to the admins. Moreover, I'm apparently the only one having these problems so I don't think they will take the time to help only one student.